# Ising Model with All Spins Interacting with All Other Spins

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, partition-function

I am studying the Ising model with all spins interacting with all other spins and have formulated $Z$. I am trying to understand what it means to study at large N but not infinite N. I know that at large N, solving for the critical point amounts to finding the minima in the integrand in the boltzmann weight (inside $Z$), but how can I show that the system will deviate from the result at large N?

Comment: By $Z$, I presume you mean the partition function. Can you write your $Z$ so that we can see what you mean here?

Comment: Check on google as a keyword "mean field approximation"